# After hiding in an attic, how did Maj Gen Urquhart and his men flee?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-bridge-too-far

In [1:29:30](https://youtu.be/H21zi9hj9-A?t=5370)/2:56:12 of *A Bridge Too Far* (1977), Maj Gen Roy Urquhart and his few men are hiding in an attic volunteered by a Dutch couple. Nazi soldiers surround them, but how did they escape and flee to their side?

Answer (score 1):

They do not escape on their own. They had help from other soldiers.

Watch from [1:50:00](https://youtu.be/H21zi9hj9-A?t=6604)